# Ошибка aiogram.utils.exceptions.BadRequest: Unsupported parse_mode, aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

```
async def profile(message: types.Message):
    cursor = conn.execute("SELECT money FROM users").fetchone()
    balance = str(cursor[0])
    
    await message.bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Монет", balance)
```

Как решить проблему?

Answer (score 1):

В методе `send_message` вы передаете переменную `balance` как отдельный аргумент, судя по всему это должна быть часть сообщения. Все должно выглядеть следующим образом:

```py
async def profile(message: types.Message):
    cursor = conn.execute("SELECT money FROM users").fetchone()
    balance = str(cursor[0])
    
    await message.bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"Монет: {balance}")
```